# What is the meaning of 'lean all in my bladder'?

Tags: idiom-meaning, lyrics

This verse comes from the song 'Old town roads' and I've never heard it before, can't find a definition/explanation online either.

Thank you !

Comment: Context needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming [Genus](https://genius.com/16899522) Lyrics' "Verified Artist" icon is correct, the actual author, Lil Nas X, has commentary on this line

> ARTIST 
>   Lil Nas X 5,977
>   3 months ago
>   This second verse is where I’m in this better lifestyle. I have me a brand new tractor. I’m on some Lean–not trying to endorse that, by the way. But I’m in a higher place now.

I believe "Lean" is one [street name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_drank) for a recreational drink using prescription strength [cough syrup](https://web.archive.org/web/20080516114703/http://www.tsbp.state.tx.us/Newsletter/Promethazine8.htm) that contains codeine.

> The drug Promethazine with Codeine is commonly known "on the street" as "syrup" and/or "lean," the latter due to the abusers’ propensity of having difficulty in standing up straight.